# Convergence of sequence of function for a bounded sequence in the Sobolev space

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, p-laplacian

Let $u_n$ be a bounded sequence in $W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega)$. Then upto a subsequence one has
$$
u_n\to u \mbox{ weakly in}\,W_{0}^{1,p}(\Omega).
$$
How the following statement is true?
$$
\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u_n|^{p-2}\nabla u_n\cdot\nabla\phi\,dx\to\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u\cdot\nabla\phi\,dx\,\,\forall\,\phi\in{C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)}.
$$

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? Please edit it into the question.

Comment: YES. PLEASE SEE LEMMA 3.9 IN THE ARTICLE : https://ejde.math.txstate.edu/Volumes/2012/35/belhaj.pdf

Comment: I'm wondering about the same question at the moment, have you been able to find a solution? By the way, the source you mention further requires strong convergence in $L^p$, which is probably the reason why the counterexample in the answer below works.

Comment: I think I found the solution, its explained on page 10 of the above article. It uses that $u_n$ is defined as solution to the eigenvalue problem (1.6). We can apply the inverse of the p-Laplacian to this equation, so on the left-hand side we get exactly $u_n$. For the right-hand side we know strong $L^\frac{p}{p-1}$ convergence from the strong $L^p$ convergence of $u_n$, so the application of the inverse $p$-Laplacian yields strong $W^{1,p}$-convergence which allows us to identify the limit of the desired integral.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is true. This could be a counterexample:
Let $\Omega = (0,1)$ and
$$
f_n(x)
:=
\begin{cases}
 0 & x < \frac12 \text{ and } \sin(4 \, \pi \, n\, x) > 0 ,\\
 2 & x < \frac12 \text{ and } \sin(4 \, \pi \, n\, x) \le 0, \\
 -1 & x \ge \frac12.
\end{cases}
$$
We set $u_n(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \mathrm{d}t$. One can check that $u_n \in W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for all $p \in (1,\infty)$
and $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ for $$u(x) = \begin{cases} x & x \le \frac12, \\ 1-x & x \ge \frac12.\end{cases}$$
However,
$$
\int_0^1 |\nabla u_n|^{p-2} \nabla u_n \cdot\nabla\varphi \, \mathrm{d}x
\to
2^{p-2} \, \int_0^{\frac12} \nabla\varphi \,\mathrm{d}x 
-
\int_{\frac12}^1 \nabla\varphi\,\mathrm{d}x
=
(2^{p-2} + 1)\, \varphi(\frac12)\\
\ne
2 \, \varphi(\frac12)
=
\int_0^1 |\nabla u|^{p-2} \nabla u \cdot\nabla\varphi \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
unless $p = 2$.